# Another 10-letter word

Tags: word, wordplay

> 2,3,4,5 - will make you scratch
>   6,9,7,10 - descendant
>   3,10,2,4,8 - deception
>   1,2,3 - smack

What is the 10-letter word?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer:

> HITCHHIKER

Explanation:

> 2,3,4,5: ITCH will make you scratch
> 6,9,7,10: HEIR ~ descendant
> 3,10,2,4,8: TRICK ~ deception
> 1,2,3: HIT ~ smack

---

**Feedback section**

I got this by first thinking about the first clue: "will make you scratch". This clue was probably too easy, since there's basically only one thing it could be and it gives you half of the solution right away. Then the fourth clue, "smack", has 2 letters already given, so it's easy to finish that one off and get the entire first half of the word. At that point, one can simply *guess* the full solution and then verify one's guess.